# Change H1 content to lowercase with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lowercase

I'm looking for a way to tranform my H1's content (actually in uppercase) to lowercase.
Ideally, it could be great to change it to the capitalize css setting of text-tranform property if exist in jquery.Why in jquery ? because the css way doesn't allowed me to do so ..
This is my starting code:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
var h1content = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$(this).text().toLowerCase();
 });
```

thanks

EDIT: fix it with adding this tips to the JS way , https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Sass code:

```
h1.titre-vdl{
    color: $violet;
    &::first-letter{
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can apply the css rule using jQuery: `$('h1').css({ textTransform: 'lowercase' });` See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLcud0La/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-transform` css property to h1 tag to convert text to lowercase

```
$('h1').css('text-transform','lowercase');
```

Comment: your way work, but I would to transform to capitalize in the end..and css doesn't allow me to transform from uppercase to capitalize, only to lowercase, so can I transform to capitalize after transforming into lowercase ?

Answer (score 0):

An `h1` doesn't have a value, it has `text()` or `html()`.

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text().toLowerCase() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass the value in the method [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('h1').each(function() {
  var h1content = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
  $(this).text(h1content);
});
```

I recommend you to do it with `css`:

```
h1{
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

```
$('h1').text(function(_, text){
    return text.toLowerCase();
});
```

However I will go with [@JayeshChitroda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3273838/jayesh-chitroda) apprach

Answer (score 0):

**Use html or text:**

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text().toLowerCase() );
});
```

Or

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html().toLowerCase() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure javascript code

```
var h1Elements = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
for (var ele of h1Elements) {
  ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
  console.log(ele.innerHTML)
}
```