# Change text from uppercase to lowercase jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change text from uppercase to lowercase but its not working

This is the code I have tried

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="brand_name">
    <a href="#"> A-RET-TZ 0.1 %</a>
</div>
```

JS I have tried

```
$('.brand_name').val().toLowerCase();
```

Problem I have is the text on page generated with uppercase by default

Anybody please suggest

Comment: `$('.brand_name a').val()` will point the original text that you require.

Comment: I tried with $('.brand_name a') as well but no luck

Comment: You should try using the helper function of `.val()` with the same selector. Sorry, I was wrong by mentioning `.val()`, you should use `.text()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change H1 content to lowercase with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182236/change-h1-content-to-lowercase-with-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method  with callback function to update the text content based on old content.

```js
$('.brand_name a').text(function(i, oldText) {
  return oldText.toLowerCase();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand_name">
  <a href="#"> A-RET-TZ 0.1 %</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This can also be achieved using pure CSS.

```css
div.brand_name > a {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand_name">
  <a href="#"> A-RET-TZ 0.1 %</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use that if that's actually all of your requirements.

Comment: I wish if I could use that but, I tried jquery way because I wanted to format the text in text-transform:captilize but that was not working so using jQuery way to first get it in lowercase and then from CSS making it to Capitlize

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the text of `anchor` element, [`.text(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) method can be used.

```js
$('.brand_name a').text(function(i, text) {
  return text.toLowerCase();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand_name">
  <a href="#"> A-RET-TZ 0.1 %</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla javascript way, it's nice to have a little variety

```js
document.querySelector(".brand_name a").innerHTML = document.querySelector(".brand_name a").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
```

```html
<div class="brand_name">
  <a href="#"> A-RET-TZ 0.1 %</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` property [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqcse2ro/#&togetherjs=xQdUbqHVkb):

JS:

```
var $this = $('.brand_name a');
$this.text($this.text().toLowerCase());
```